# Tableau: Graph X on month with different year as colored lines

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to recreate the following Excel-created graph in Tableau. My data has traffic organized by month-year Eg., 01-01-2016, 02-01-2016 ...etc. for each year. Would changing the data format be required, or can I work with this as is?

[image: Graph showing traffic by year and month]

I'm following [the tutorial here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_line.htm) but the closest I can get is:

[image: Current state of things]

Comment: Change the mark type from Bar to Line and you'll be set.

Comment: I am a terrible noob! Appreciate the help! I will set this as the answer if you want to create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this easily.
1. Change the marks card type from Automatic to Line.

[image: Marks card]

2. Use Show Me (upper right) and select the icon for the line chart.

[image: Marks type]

Additionally, here is some information on Discrete vs Continuous Pills which cause many new users confusion.

Discrete = Distinct buckets like apples, oranges, peaches, etc
Continuous = Any values on an axis like percentage, sales, etc

For dates, discrete dates are *parts* of the month like days (1, 2, 3...), months (Jan, Feb, March...).  A continuous date would be Jan 2019, Feb 2019, etc (these are truncated dates because they include the entire date starting from earlier in time to later in time.

In the picture, the list in green is continuous and the list in blue is discrete.
[image: Discrete vs Continuous]